# Функция подсчета лидера чисел

Tags: python

Создать функцию которая рассчитывает число лидер. Число считается Лидером, если оно больше суммы всех элементов справа от него.
Основные условия:

1. Входящий список содержит не менее 3 элементов.
2. Список входных чисел может содержать как положительные, так и отрицательные числа.
3. Числа могут повторяться
4. Возвращаемый список должен содержать числа в том же порядке, в котором они встречаются в исходном списке.
5. Отсутствие элементов справа от числа расценивается как 0.
   Написал функцию, но она почему то не выводит последнее число и не выводит отрицательные числа.

```
def get_leaders(numbers: list) -> list:
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(numbers)-1):
        if numbers[i] == 0:
            return []
        if numbers[i] >= numbers[i+1] + numbers[i+1]:
            new_list.append(numbers[i])
    return new_list

print(get_leaders([1, 2, 3, 4, 0]))  # == [4]
print(get_leaders([16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2]))  # == [17, 5, 2]
print(get_leaders([16, 8, 4, 2, 1]))  # == [16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
print(get_leaders([0, 0, 0, 0]))  # == []
print(get_leaders([-1, -1, -1, -1]))   # == [-1, -1]
print(get_leaders([-45, -23, -16, -1, 1]))  # == [1]
print(get_leaders([0, -1, -29, 3, 2]))  # == [0, -1, 3, 2]
print(get_leaders([5, -2, 0]))  # == [5]
```

Comment: Ок, код есть. А вопрос тогда в чем?

Comment: Написал функцию, но она почему то не выводит последнее число и не выводит отрицательные числа. Вместо указанных значений при вызове, выводит, вот эти значения: [4]
[17, 5]
[16, 8, 4, 2]
[]
[-1, -1, -1]
[-45, -23]
[]
[5]

Comment: `if numbers[i] >= numbers[i+1] + numbers[i+1]:` - это не похоже на "оно больше суммы всех элементов справа от него". Вы тут сравниваете с одним удвоенным элементом справа от текущего числа. Ну и вот это условие `if numbers[i] == 0:` - его нет в тексте задачи. Подсказка: для первого решения, не оптимизированного, можно использовать встроенную функцию `sum` и срезы, проверка условий будет очень простая, хотя решение и будет сложности `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Пробую так  if numbers[i] >= sum(numbers[i+1: -1]): суммирую следующий элемент с элементами до конца списка, все равно, не получается

Comment: Сделал вот так:     for i in range(0, len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] >= sum(numbers[i+1: -1]):, считает все правильно но теперь появились в 1, 3 и 8 тесте лишние нули

Comment: @Константин Уберите `-1` - чтобы получить весь список до конца можно просто не указывать конечный индекс среза, т.е. `sum(numbers[i+1:])`, а у вас выпадал последний элемент из суммирования из-за `-1`.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно перебирать список задом наперёд, тогда проще и быстрее

```
def get_leaders(numbers: list) -> list:
    new_list, s = [], 0
    for i in reversed(numbers):
        if i > s:
            new_list.insert(0, i)
        s += i
    return new_list


print(get_leaders([1, 2, 3, 4, 0]))  # == [4]
print(get_leaders([16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2]))  # == [17, 5, 2]
print(get_leaders([16, 8, 4, 2, 1]))  # == [16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
print(get_leaders([0, 0, 0, 0]))  # == []
print(get_leaders([-1, -1, -1, -1]))  # == [-1, -1]
print(get_leaders([-45, -23, -16, -1, 1]))  # == [1]
print(get_leaders([0, -1, -29, 3, 2]))  # == [0, -1, 3, 2]
print(get_leaders([5, -2, 0]))  # == [5]
```

```
[4]
[17, 5, 2]
[16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
[]
[-1, -1]
[1]
[0, -1, 3, 2]
[5]
```

Comment: Решение правильное, но сам подход решения элементарных заданий за кого-то он порочный. Человек не учится, если такое решают за него. Хотя тут бывает сложно нащупать грань где можно давать код, а где нет.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, без специальной комиссии по разрешению публикации решений сложно :) почему-то ответы допустимы сразу после публикации вопроса. Вот если бы нужно было, например, 5 голосов, чтобы появилась возможность ответить на вопрос, была бы другая ситуация. К слову, голосов за закрытие вопроса по причине "Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии..." при 26 просмотрах нет.